# basic daterange picker angular js. double entry

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am hoping to create a date range picker using angular js and bootstrap.

I have two text boxes and they both open the date picker box.  However it enters the date into both boxes at the same time?

**html snippet**

```
  <div class="form-group">

      <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control date" id="dateFrom" placeholder="From" ng-click="open($event)"   class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" >
          <input type="text" class="form-control date" id="dateTo"   placeholder="To" ng-click="open($event)"   class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" >
      </div>

  </div>
```

**Javascript snippet**

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.open = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        $scope.opened = true;
  };
  $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[1];
});
```

You can see **[working plunker example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CEILZQpqnl399hvYdCW1?p=preview)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using same model for both fields,  ng-model="dt";

Just use two different model  ng-model="dtFrom" for dateFrom and  ng-model="dtTo" for dateTo:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control date" id="dateFrom" placeholder="From" ng-click="open($event)"   class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dtFrom" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" >
<input type="text" class="form-control date" id="dateTo"   placeholder="To" ng-click="open($event)"   class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dtTo" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" >
```

Here is [the working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lZIWcq?p=preview)

AngularJS documentation on [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) should help much, I think.